# Bluetooth Connection (Android Sockets)

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, beagleboneblack, bluez

***A little bit about my current setup:***

Currently I have a Android program split into a bunch of different fragments.
The home fragment scans for a Bluetooth connection with a specific MAC Address, and socket UUID. This connection works fine (no problem yet).

The broadcasting Bluetooth server is a beaglebone black that is running ubuntu and is utilizing bluez to broadcast a specific service with a specific UUID.

Problem:
When I switch to the gallery fragment, I then attempt to use the already connected Bluetooth service to send data (pictures).

Where I run into trouble is with the command `outputStream.write(msgBuffer);`. It returns with a "null" error.

***So far for debugging I have done the following:***

I was curious to see if the original connection ever worked (in the home fragment), so after I connected to the Bluetooth server with a call to connect(), I then tested it with a call to socket.getConnected(). This returned true, meaning the Bluetooth socket must be connected to the Bluetooth server.

I then wanted to see what was happening in the gallery fragment. 
Before sending my data with the outputStream.write(msgBuffer); command, I ran socket.getConnected() which returned false. Thus meaning the socket must be disconnected.... ***Why is the bluetooth server now disconnected? Do I have to do anything special to keep the bluetooth connection open? Do I have to do anything special to keep the connection alive when switching fragments?***

What would be causing my connection to disconnect in the time between these two events?

Below are my two fragments.

**Home Fragment**

```
    package edu.umass.ecs.chalkmaster3000;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;  
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Created by Oskoss on 11/16/13.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final int BT_ACTIVITY = 5;
    public int i;

    ActivityCommunication activityCallback;

    public interface ActivityCommunication{
        public void updateColors(int color);
        public String getAddress();
        public UUID getUUID();
        public BluetoothSocket getBTSocket();
        public BluetoothAdapter getBTAdapter();
        public void setConnectionStatus(boolean status);
        public boolean getConnectionStatus();
        public View getView(int viewID);
        public Context getContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            activityCallback = (ActivityCommunication) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement ActivityCommunication");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
       View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment,container,false);
        ImageView robotImage = (ImageView) V.findViewById(R.id.robotStatus);
        ImageButton staticRobotImage = (ImageButton) V.findViewById(R.id.button);
        TextView status = (TextView) V.findViewById(R.id.textView_Status);
        if(activityCallback.getConnectionStatus()){
            V.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
            activityCallback.updateColors(1);
            activityCallback.setConnectionStatus(true);

            status.setText("Bluetooth Connected to Dusty!");
            robotImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.happy_dusty);
            Animation pulse = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activityCallback.getContext(), R.anim.pulse);
            robotImage.startAnimation(pulse);
        }
        else{
           //checkBTStates();
            if(BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()==null){
                V.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
                staticRobotImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sad_dusty);
                //robotImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sad_dusty);
                status.setText("Your phone has no Bluetooth :/!");
                activityCallback.updateColors(0);
                activityCallback.setConnectionStatus(false);
            }
            else{
                V.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                staticRobotImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sad_dusty);
                //robotImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sad_dusty);
                activityCallback.updateColors(2);
                activityCallback.setConnectionStatus(false);
            }

            final ImageButton button = (ImageButton) V.findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    checkBTStates();
                }
            });
        }
        return V;
    }

    private void checkBTStates() {
        BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = activityCallback.getBTAdapter();
        View currentView = activityCallback.getView(R.id.home_fragment);
        ImageButton staticRobotImage = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.button);
        TextView status = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView_Status);
        // Check for Bluetooth support and then check to make sure it is turned on
        if(btAdapter==null) {
            status.setText("Fatal Error: Bluetooth doesn't seem to be supported on your device! :(");
            staticRobotImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sad_dusty);
            //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(activityCallback.getContext(), "Fatal Error: Bluetooth doesn't seem to be supported on your device! :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            //toast.show();
            currentView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
            activityCallback.updateColors(0);
            activityCallback.setConnectionStatus(false);
           //robotImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sad_dusty);
        }
        else {
                if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    connectBT();
                    }
                else {
                        //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
                        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, BT_ACTIVITY);
                }
        }
    }

    public String address = "00:02:72:3F:86:B3";

    final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    public  BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    // Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;



    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    private void connectBT(){
        ImageButton staticRobotImage = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.button);
        TextView status = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView_Status);
        try {
            btSocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            status.setText("Fatal Error in onResume() and socket create failed");
            //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(activityCallback.getContext(), "Fatal Error in onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            //toast.show();
        }

        View currentView = activityCallback.getView(R.id.home_fragment);
        ImageView robotImage = (ImageView) activityCallback.getView(R.id.robotStatus);


        // Two things are needed to make a connection:
        //   A MAC address, which we got above.
        //   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
        //     UUID for SPP.


        // Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
        // when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
        try {
            btSocket.connect();
            if(btSocket.isConnected()){

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(activityCallback.getContext(), "socket is connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            }
            currentView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
            activityCallback.updateColors(1);
            activityCallback.setConnectionStatus(true);
            ImageButton connect = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.button);
            ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) connect.getParent();
            status.setText("Bluetooth Connected to Dusty!");
            robotImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.happy_dusty);
            Animation pulse = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activityCallback.getContext(), R.anim.pulse);
            robotImage.startAnimation(pulse);
            if(null!=layout) //for safety only  as you are doing onClick
              layout.removeView(connect);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                staticRobotImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sad_dusty);
                currentView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
                activityCallback.updateColors(0);
                //robotImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sad_dusty);
                status.setText("No Bluetooth server broadcasting to connect to....");
                activityCallback.setConnectionStatus(false);
                //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(activityCallback.getContext(),"No Bluetooth server broadcasting to connect to....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                //toast.show();
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                status.setText("Fatal Error in onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure");
                //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(activityCallback.getContext(),"Fatal Error in onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                //toast.show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        TextView status = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView_Status);
        ImageButton staticRobotImage = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.button);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        View currentView = activityCallback.getView(R.id.home_fragment);
        switch(requestCode){
            case BT_ACTIVITY:
                if(resultCode == -1){
                    i = 50; //Stop asking the user to enable bluetooth
                    status.setText("Bluetooth is now on!");
                    connectBT();
                    Toast.makeText(activityCallback.getContext(), "Bluetooth is now on!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(resultCode == 0){
                    staticRobotImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sad_dusty);
                    currentView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                    activityCallback.updateColors(2);
                    //robotImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.sad_dusty);
                    activityCallback.setConnectionStatus(false);
                    status.setText("This application requires Bluetooth...Maybe try to turn it on?! ;)");
                    //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(activityCallback.getContext(), "This application requires Bluetooth...Maybe try to turn it on?! ;)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    //toast.show();
                }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Gallery Fragment**

```
 package edu.umass.ecs.chalkmaster3000;


import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;



public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {
    private int count;
    int id;
    private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
    private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
    private String[] arrPath;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    public OutputStream outStream = null;
    public ViewGroup container1 = null;

    ActivityCommunication activityCallback;

    public interface ActivityCommunication{
        public String getAddress();
        public UUID getUUID();
        public BluetoothSocket getBTSocket();
        public boolean getConnectionStatus();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            activityCallback = (ActivityCommunication) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement ActivityCommunication");
        }
    }
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        container1 = container;
        View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery, container, false);
        final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
        Cursor imagecursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                columns,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
                new String[]{"%/Robo Pics/%"},
                null);

        int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
        this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count];
        this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
        this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
            imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
            id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
            int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    getActivity().getContentResolver(), id,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
            arrPath[i]= imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
        }
        GridView imagegrid = (GridView) V.findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
        imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

        final Button selectBtn = (Button) V.findViewById(R.id.selectBtn);
        final Button previewBtn = (Button) V.findViewById(R.id.previewBtn);
        final Button deleteBtn = (Button) V.findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);
        selectBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(activityCallback.getConnectionStatus()){
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
                    int cnt = 0;
                    String selectImages = "";

                    for (int i =0; i<len; i++)
                    {
                        if (thumbnailsselection[i]){
                            cnt++;
                            selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i];
                        }
                    }
                    if (cnt == 0){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "Dusty can't draw anything unless you select an image! Sadface",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else if(cnt>1){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "Dusty is amazing but he can't draw two images at one time! Sadface",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else {
                           byte sendArray[] = readBytes(selectImages);
                           sendBTData(sendArray);
                    }
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You need to first connect to Dusty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        previewBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                    final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
                    int cnt = 0;
                    String selectImages = "";

                    for (int i =0; i<len; i++)
                    {
                        if (thumbnailsselection[i]){
                            cnt++;
                            selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i];
                        }
                    }
                    if (cnt == 0){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "There is nothing to preview! Sadface",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else if(cnt>1){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "You can't preview more than one thing! Silly",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + selectImages), "image/*");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
            }
        });

        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                    final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
                    int cnt = 0;
                    String[] storage = new String[len];

                    for (int i =0; i<len; i++)
                    {
                        if (thumbnailsselection[i]){
                            cnt++;
                            storage[i] = arrPath[i];
                        }
                    }
                    if (cnt == 0){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "Can't delete nothing! Silly",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        AlertDialog diaBox = AskOption(storage);
                        diaBox.show();


                    }
            }
        });
      return V;
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ImageAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.galleryitem, null);
                holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
                holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.yup123);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.checkbox.setId(position);
            holder.imageview.setId(position);
            holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    int id = cb.getId();
                    if (thumbnailsselection[id]){
                        cb.setChecked(false);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                    } else {
                        cb.setChecked(true);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    RelativeLayout row = (RelativeLayout) v.getParent();
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) row.getChildAt(2);
                    id=cb.getId();
                    if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                        cb.setChecked(false);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                    } else {
                        cb.setChecked(true);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnails[position]);
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
            holder.id = position;
            return convertView;
        }
    }
    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageview;
        CheckBox checkbox;
        int id;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    private void sendBTData(byte[] msgBuffer){
        String address = activityCallback.getAddress();
        UUID MY_UUID = activityCallback.getUUID();
        BluetoothSocket btSocket = activityCallback.getBTSocket();
        try {
            btSocket.connect();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                e.printStackTrace();
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
        Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Sending message to server...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast1.show();

        try {
            outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Fatal Error in onResume() and output stream creation failed:" + e.getMessage() + ".", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }

        try {
            if(btSocket.isConnected()){

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "socket is connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
            else{
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NOT CONNECTEDDDDDD", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
            outStream.write(msgBuffer);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Images are now being sent through outter space to Robo for drawing!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (address.equals("00:00:00:00:00:00")) {
                msg = msg + ".\n\nUpdate your server address from 00:00:00:00:00:00 to the correct address on line 37 in the java code";
            }
            else{
                msg = msg +  ".\n\nCheck that the SPP UUID: " + MY_UUID.toString() + " exists on server.\n\n";
            }
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

    public byte[] readBytes(String filePath){
        BitmapFactory cute = new BitmapFactory();
        Bitmap picSend = cute.decodeFile(filePath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        picSend.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream1);
        byte picByteSend[] = stream1.toByteArray();
        return picByteSend;

    }
    public AlertDialog AskOption(final String[] toBeDeleted)
    {
        AlertDialog myQuittingDialogBox =new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                //set message, title, and icon
                .setTitle("Delete Confirmation")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete the selected pictures?")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.new_pic)

                .setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < toBeDeleted.length; i++) {
                            if (toBeDeleted[i] != null) {
                                File f = new File(toBeDeleted[i]);
                                if (f.exists()) {
                                    if (f.delete()) {

                                        Log.w("DELETED", "file Deleted");
                                    } else {
                                        Log.w("NOT DELETED", "file not Deleted");
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            getActivity().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                                    Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
                            FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
                            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
                            Fragment newFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("gallery");;
                            newFragment.onDestroy();
                            ft.remove(newFragment);
                            ft.replace(container1.getId(),newFragment);
                            //container is the ViewGroup of current fragment
                            ft.addToBackStack(null);
                            ft.commit();
                        }
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                })

                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                })
                .create();

        return myQuittingDialogBox;

    }
}
```

As always thank you!

Edits:

Tried to clean this up a bit.
If you don't understand this, can you tell me what you don't understand so I can provide more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't passing the sockets correctly between the fragments, and therefore opened up multiple sockets.......needed to take a break from the project to realize such a silly mistake.